# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when creating NSMutalbeArray of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am trying to populate an array of dictionary. But xcode says EXC_BAD_ACCESS

It's a basic operation. where is the error?

```
@interface MenuViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;
@end

@implementation MenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuHomeIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuFindIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuProfileIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuSettingsIcon.png",@"image", nil],nil];

}
```

I tried another way but the result is same:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:4];

    [self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuHomeIcon.png",@"image", nil]];
    [self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuFindIcon.png",@"image", nil]];
    [self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuProfileIcon.png",@"image", nil]];
    [self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuSettingsIcon.png",@"image", nil]];

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A @ is missing before the image name string

```
[self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title","MenuHomeIcon.png",@"image", nil]];
```

should be

```
[self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuHomeIcon.png",@"image", nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to have @ to one of parameter "MenuHomeIcon.png"

```
self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuHomeIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuFindIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuProfileIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuSettingsIcon.png",@"image", nil],nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

try these..

@ is missing before the image name string in your self.items..

do these..

```
self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuHomeIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuFindIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuProfileIcon.png",@"image", nil],
                                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuSettingsIcon.png",@"image", nil],nil];
```

and for addObject..

```
[self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuHomeIcon.png",@"image", nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you was forgot to add '@'
so Just add this

```
self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",@"MenuHomeIcon.png",@"image", nil]];
```

Answer (score -1):

All the above answers look fine, but could it be that you want to add an actual image and no file?
If so you should add something like this:

```
[self.items addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"home",@"title",[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuHomeIcon.png"],@"image", nil]];
```